# Notification if no balance in sim card using android studio

Tags: notifications, smsmanager

guys is it possible to know if the sim card has a balance/load using android Studio.

i just want to notified if sim card don't have a load.

I have a switch, which is use to send a constant text using Smsmanager...

[here is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJlfy.png)

if i try to switch outlet 1  (insert trigger where in no load detected) then the switch will not on

By the way  I do send that constant message using this

//function o send message sms

```
 private void sendMessage(String phoneNo, String Message) {
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, Message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switching...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sending Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: hi guys trying to figure out what will I do to deal with the trigger thing to switch off the switch button before opening the applcation this is my sample image of text iwill update my question